# Why is there no serial option under advanced?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, serial, raspi-config

I am trying to set up serial communication for my new PI 3. When I go to Raspi-Config to enable or disable serial under advanced options, it is not there. However, it is under the interface option. Why is this, and is the latter option the same as `advanced -> serial`? I am running Raspbian 8 Jessie on PI 3.

Comment: Technically, serial is a type of interface, so it makes sense that it goes there. That being said, your question doesn't really have an objective answer other than, "because that's where they put it".

Comment: Well, I have not seen this until yesterday. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer is they tidied up the menus and moved the option from Advanced to Interfaces.